# is it possible to make real time progress/percentage bar in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Below code is simple jquery progress bar. Is there any way to update progress value (that is 67 rite now)dynamically on ajaxStart and reach this value to 100 on ajaxStop()?

```
<head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />



    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                **value: 67**
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>


 <body>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, but it's *really* not worth the effort. How much data are you uploading via AJAX?

Comment: Well, there's nothing impossible if you have the time machine... Otherwise it's a bit inconvenient trying to guess the ajax request duration.

Comment: What are you trying to measure?

Comment: @meagar i have uploaded multiple images at a time via HTML5 data may be 10-15 MB in one request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targetting HTML5 browsers only, then try whats decribed here:[Jquery Ajax Progress in HTML5](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)

The traditional way to go about this would be to show a spinning gif, instead of the loader.

Ajax request wont be too long in most of the cases & hence all the effort in trying for the same is lost.

However it is not uncommon for a progress bar to be shown. The problem is, older browsers did not share this info with JS & the developers were left to using hacks like,

- Using the help of flash. Flash plugin could keep track of the amount
  of data uploaded & hence tell the javascript.
- A method of approximating the time also works in certain cases.
- The only choice that remains is to ping the server continuously to know how much transfer took place.